# Bootstrap Multiselect in ASP.Net Core Razor Page does not show the drop-down when clicked

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, bootstrap-multiselect

I am unable to get the bootstrap multiselect drop-down to work in my View. I simply get the button pictured here
[image].

However, clicking on it does not trigger the drop-down to appear.

Below is my code snippet and the css/js files I'm including. I did not catch any errors in the browser dev tools. Am I missing anything?

```
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Initialize the plugin: -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using CDN's of CSS and JS and you are not fowling correct order that's why it's not working check this code it's working for me.

```
    <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Initialize the plugin: -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
    });
</script>

<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, i am having same issue. I pasted your code still not working, not sure what you mean by "not fowling correct order ". can you please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks @Hafiz  I later came to know what you meant by "following order". I pasted javascript at the very start before css and it worked. :)